# Can ghci tell us what instance of a class is being used

Tags: haskell

Here's some ghci

```
> :t (<*>)
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
> :t allEqual
allEqual :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
> :t allEqual <*> reverse
allEqual <*> reverse :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
> :t reverse
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
```

I'm trying to work out what exactly is the instance of the applicative in `allEqual <*> reverse`.

I tried to reason that

```
f (a -> b) :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool
f a :: [a] -> [a]
f b :: [a] -> Bool
```

but this does not make sense to be since `f b` is related to `a`.

Is their anyway to get ghci to tell me what applicative `f` is  actually being used here. If not how do haskellers reason about this stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `-ddump-ds` to get GHC to show you what instance it's using, like this:

```
GHCi, version 9.8.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> :{
ghci| allEqual :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
ghci| allEqual = undefined -- or your actual definition
ghci| :}
ghci> :set -ddump-ds -dsuppress-all -dno-suppress-type-applications
ghci> x = allEqual <*> reverse

==================== Desugared ====================
letrec {
  x_aR1
    = \ @a_aSP $dEq_aT1 ->
        let { $dEq_aSQ = $dEq_aT1 } in
        let { $dApplicative_aSL = $fApplicativeFUN @[a_aSP] } in
        letrec {
          x_aSW
            = <*>
                @((->) [a_aSP])
                $dApplicative_aSL
                @[a_aSP]
                @Bool
                (allEqual @a_aSP $dEq_aSQ)
                (reverse @a_aSP); } in
        x_aSW; } in
returnIO
  @[Any]
  (: @Any
     (unsafeCoerce#
        @LiftedRep
        @LiftedRep
        @(forall {a}. Eq a => [a] -> Bool)
        @Any
        x_aR1)
     ([] @Any))


ghci>
```

The `@((->) [a_aSP])` after the `<*>` in the output means that it's using the instance for functions (listed as the `Applicative ((->) r)` instance in [the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative)).

Alternatively, you could figure it out without GHC's help just by looking at the types, like this:

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
allEqual :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
```

For simplicity's sake, I'll alpha-convert the latter two types to not reuse the `a` type variable:

```
allEqual :: Eq t => [t] -> [t] -> Bool
reverse :: [t] -> [t]
```

Remember that `->` is right-associative, and it can also be written in prefix form, so `[t] -> [t] -> Bool` is the same as `(->) [t] ([t] -> Bool)`. Since `allEqual` is the first parameter to `<*>`, its type must unify with `f (a -> b)`. Similarly, as the second parameter, the type of `reverse` must unify with `f a`. When you plug all of that in, you get that `f` must be `(->) [t]`, `a` must be `[t]`, and `b` must be `Bool`. A quick sanity check that this is correct is to observe that `f b` is then `[t] -> Bool`, which after alpha-equivalence is the same type GHC inferred as the output of `allEqual <*> reverse`. Since `f` is what the `Applicative` instance is needed on, it must be using the instance for `(->) [t]` (functions that take a list as an argument). Doing `:instances ((->) [t])` will show you `instance Applicative ((->) [t]) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’`, but the instance that actually gets used is more general, one for any kind of function. Once you found the function arrow, doing `:info (->)` would show you that: `instance Applicative ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’`.

Answer (score 7):

A quick trick I sometimes use is to add a typed hole as in `` (polymorphicValue `asTypeOf` _) ``.

More precisely, `asTypeOf` is a function defined as

```
asTypeOf :: t -> t -> t
asTypeOf x y = x
```

It's very similar to `const`, but it *forces* its two arguments `x` and `y` to have the same type.

Adding a typed hole `_` in the middle of an expression tells GHC to raise a type error telling what type should be used to fill the hole.

Hence, `` (thing `asTypeOf` _) `` asks GHC to print the type of `thing`, which is very useful when `thing` is polymorphic.

Let's apply this to your case:

```
ghci> :t allEqual <*> reverse
allEqual <*> reverse :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
```

First, we move `(<*>)` to prefix notation.

```
ghci> :t (<*>) allEqual reverse
(<*>) allEqual reverse :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
```

Then, we insert the typed hole:

```
ghci> :t ((<*>) `asTypeOf` _) allEqual reverse
    * Found hole:
        _ :: ([a] -> [a] -> Bool) -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> Bool
      Valid hole fits include
        (<*>) :: forall (f :: * -> *) t u.
                 Applicative f =>
                 f (t -> u) -> f t -> f u
          with (<*>) @((->) [a]) @[a] @Bool
```

We get to know the specific instantiated type of `(<*>)`, i.e. `([a] -> [a] -> Bool) -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> Bool`, as well an explanation of how we got that type. Indeed, the part

```
(<*>) @((->) [a]) @[a] @Bool
```

Shows that `<*>` was used according to the `(->) [a]` applicative, and types `[a]` and `Bool`. We can depict that as follows:

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (t -> u) -> f t -> f u
  where f ~ (->) [a]
        t ~ [a]
        u ~ Bool
```